# Resolve namespaces from another PHP project

Tags: php, namespaces

I have two separate PHP projects on my server - Project1 and Project2. Project1 has some namespaces defined, e.g. 'common'. Project1 also has a class named DbPlace which looks like this:

```
class DbPlace extends \common\DbModel
{
...
}
```

I would like to use this class in Project2 so in one of Project2 files I import it like this:

```
require_once "path/to/Project1/src/classes/db/DbPlace.php";
```

Class DbPlace.php is successfully found, however I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'common\DbModel' not found in D:\xampp\Project1\src\classes\db\DbPlace.php on line 6
```

As you can see, it fails to find the namespaced class DbModel. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the parent class

```
require_once "path/to/Project1/src/classes/common/DbModel.php";
require_once "path/to/Project1/src/classes/db/DbPlace.php";
```

See [spl_autoload](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload.php) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for interesting tools for autoloading and to get rid of require and include.

Comment: Thanks for links about autoload.